# CruiseControl.net and SourceSafe periodic error

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, visual-sourcesafe

I'm using CruiseControl.net with Visual SourceSafe and every now and again the build fails with this error:

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: No VSS database (srcsafe.ini) found.  Use the SSDIR environment variable or run netsetup.
```

The documentation says this is due to running the CC.net service as Local System which doesn't have permission to connect to other machines. I am running the service under that user, but the build works 19 times out of 20 so I don't think it's a lack of permissions.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to builds running while I'm not logged into the machine.